# Error iteration with ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects, describing seats.
each seat object looks like this:

```
ID: 1
platz: 1
status: 1
title: "Sitzplatz #1"
userID: 1
```

now I used AngularJS with ng-options to iterate over my object array like this:

```
<select ng-options="s.status for s in seating"></select>
```

but i got an error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngOptions
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:6:416
    at s (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:63:198)
    at s (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:63:265)
    at u (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:66:175)
    at g (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:58:136)
    at g (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:58:153)
    at g (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:58:153)
    at g (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:58:153)
    at g (http://localhost/netconnect-4.0/assets/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:58:153) <div ng-include="'app/shared/modals/adminEditorSeating.html'" class="ng-scope">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ng-model whenever you are using ng-options.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<select ng-model="modelname" ng-options="s.status for s in seating"></select>
```